# Confused about a variable value?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a program that tells if a phrase is a palindrome or not. Here is the code the tutorial wants me to produce:

```
var text = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
var reversed = [String]()

var counter = text.count - 1

while counter >= 0 {
   reversed.append(text[counter])
   counter -=1
}
```

I have no idea why I have to add the -1 after I define the counter variable with text.count.
Shouldn't the counter -=1 in the while loop be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `arrays` in `Swift` (such as the string array that holds your text) are `zero based`.

i.e. their first element is at position zero, and last element at position `array.count-1`.

So when iterating over arrays **manually**, one wants to iterate between [0] and `[array.count-1]`.

Normally one wouldn't even consider this because you would usually not bother using manual loops and instead use `fast enumeration` or `for in`.

e.g.

```
var text = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
for letter in text.reversed() {
    print(letter)
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: because the array is zero indexed but the .count function doesn't?

Comment: @MDabbs no problems, check out my more 'Swift' way to do it... feel free to mark question as answered if happy.

Comment: no probs! Just let me know if you need more help :) Good to see new coders around here @MDabbs